# Working backwards with particles to get symmetries

Tags: physics

I was wondering whether you might be able to invent, say a new particle or multiple related ones, with their spin, mass, charge etc defined, but not only that, also work backwards to get the fundamental symmetry that spawns this particle/particle-group. Essentially you would work out the quantum field math behind it, then figure out the conserved quantity, and apply Noether's theorem to get the corresponding symmetry.

I have no idea if this would be extremely complicated or not, but it seems like a fun idea.

Comment: Maybe belongs in the physics SE. It is grotesquely complicated and has been keeping many physicists busy for about a century.